# Host WAS hosting without IIS

Tags: wcf, hosting, iis-5, was

I am using Windows XP which got IIS 5, I am facing some authentication issue during database actions. I tried impersanating but it didn't work for me.

Can I host WCF service without IIS(5) in XP machine? Please confirm this.

Comment: you need to ask a specific question.  Are you asking about authentication or are you asking about hosting WCF on XP? For the latter, a simple google search will bring you to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx#msdnwcfhc%5Ftopic5

Comment: +1 for question I might be in same situation in few weeks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only option except IIS hosting in XP will be 
i)Console Hosting.
ii)Windows Service Hosting.

Comment: You can host in any .Net app, not just console apps.

Answer (score 2):

You can host WCF service in any .NET program. The most common in your scenario is [Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx) but it doesn't have to be solution for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can not host in WAS on Windows XP since WAS requires IIS 7, but as Ladislav says, you can certainly host in any .Net program.

If you can't use IIS (perhaps because you want to use NetTCP or another non-Http protocol), and you need your host to be long running, your best bet is to use a windows service.

Check out the Self Hosting section of this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx).